# docker logs -f after container restart

Tags: docker

I am using `docker logs -f mycontainer` to check the logs.  If I restart `mycontainer` by `docker rm -f mycontainer` then `docker run -d --name mycontainer`,  I need to use `Ctrl-C` then rerun the `docker logs` command to get the logs.  I wonder if there is a better way for me to keep receiving the logs even after the container restarts.

Comment: Technically, you're not restarting the container; you're destroying it and creating a new one with the same name.  Restarting would be running `docker stop mycontainer; docker start mycontainer` or just `docker restart mycontainer`.

Answer (score 6):

As other commenters have mentioned, the "rm" command is destroying your container, not restarting it.

But to answer your question you could use something like this:

```
watch -n 0 "docker logs mycontainer"
```

The docker logs command doesn't keep running for a stopped container, but you can achieve a similar effect using the "watch" command. And since it's not a Docker command, it doesn't care if the container is running or not.

If you're on a Mac you might not have watch. It can be installed using pip. The same thing can be achieved with a one-liner bash script but I find watch to be much neater.

Comment: I actually have watch on my Mac (High Sierra) but although it looks to be updating constantly (the terminal window title and timestamp keeps updating) the logs don't. I've started and stopped the container several times with no change.

Answer (score 5):

2 things

with `docker rm -f mycontainer` you are not stopping your container, you are killing it, then you start another brand new after

you can use `docker stop mycontainer` and start or simply `docker restart mycontainer` to keep logs.

Because container are stateless, you will lose logs if you delete your container. In that case, you have to use a volume where to write your application logs. They will be on the host instead of into your container.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about the `restart` command. I've been stopping and starting like a caveman all this time. haha